# Setting vimwiki defaults

Tags: vim, grep

The situation: I was using vimwiki, I stopped for a brief flirtation with emacs/org-mode, and then ran screaming back to vim. I figured it was a good time to clean up my kludgy setup, and so I started with a fresh ~/.vim directory, installed pathogen, and I've been adding packages that way.

What's very strange is, when I go to start a new vimwiki index file, I get the message:

```
Vimwiki: Make new directory: /home/thomas/Dropbox/wiki/wiki
```

despite my .vimrc containing instead

```
let g:vimwiki_list = [{'path':'~/cerebra/wiki', 'path_html':'~/cerebra/export/html/'}]
```

That is to say, it's trying to save the wiki in a place almost, but not quite, like my previous vimwiki installation, and ignoring the new setting I've given it.

I bet if I understood how to use `find` with `grep` I could find where this setting is so that I could delete it. I examined each file in ~/.vim/bundle/vimwiki, and found no instance of the word "Dropbox" there, and it's nowhere in my vimrc.

Comment: did you try remove that line from your vimrc, using default setting which should be `$HOME/vimwiki`, does it still point to your dropbox?

Comment: I use vimwiki too, cannot reproduce your problem. did you set that variable somewhere else in your vimrc? after your vim started, what is the output of `echo g:vimwiki_list`?

Comment: This is so weird. If I comment out the `let g:vimwiki_list` line entirely, I get `Vimwiki: Make new directory: /home/thomas/Dropbox/wiki/wiki`. If I `let g:vimwiki_list = [{'path':'$HOME/vimwiki'}]`, then I get `Vimwiki: Make new directory: /home/thomas/vimwiki`

Comment: Even weirder: right now I've got my vimrc set to have

`let g:vimwiki_list = [{'path':'$HOME/cerebra/wiki', 'path_html':'$HOME/cerebra/export/html'}]`

but in response to that echo g:vimwiki_list, I get 

    `[{'path_html': '/home/thomas/Dropbox/wiki/export/html/', 'maxhi': 0, 'template_path': '/', 'path': '/home/thomas/Dropbox/wiki/wiki/', 'a
uto_export': 0, 'ext': '.wiki', 'index': 'index', 'syntax': 'default', 'nested_syntaxes': {}, 'diary_rel_path': 'diary/'}]`

Comment: are you sure you it is the only place to set vimwiki_list in your vimrc? do a search

Comment: the string `vimwiki` appears only within these four lines in my vimrc, mostly commented out:

`" Wiki Preferences (Vimwiki)

" let g:vimwiki_list = [{'path':'~/cerebra/wiki', 'path_html':'~/cerebra/export/html/'}]
let g:vimwiki_list = [{'path':'$HOME/cerebra/wiki', 'path_html':'$HOME/cerebra/export/html'}]
" let g:vimwiki_list = [{'path':'$HOME/vimwiki'}]`

Does it appear elsewhere in ~/.vim/*? That I don't know.

Comment: also I guess your `$HOME/cerebra` is a link to `/home/thomas/Dropbox/wiki` can you please check that?

Comment: oh hell, you're probably right--

Comment: so shall I add an answer for that? :D

Comment: A very embarrassing answer, yes. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the comments, it turns out, your `$HOME/cerebra` is a softlink to `/home/thomas/Dropbox/wiki`.

So vimwiki works just fine.

**small suggestion**:

You could consider to create a link in dropbox, not the other way round. dropbox supports it.

Comment: To clarify: You mean, keep the real file in my home directory, and use a link FROM the file TO dropbox, which will then sync the files. That makes a lot more sense but I didn't realize it would work. Thank you Kent!